# Timespan.Hour, returns from the range of -23 to 23 why is it a int32?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, struct

Was playing around a little bit with the TimeSpan class and I started wondering about why the properties of the timespan class are all int32s?

I understand why the constructor takes an int32 when you create your timespan, but if you look at the MSDN documentation it states:

> "The hour component of the current TimeSpan structure. The return
>   value ranges from -23 through 23."

and that the property looks like this

> public int Hours { get; }

My first instinctive thought me was that it was sharing some kind of data with TimeSpan.TotalHours, but that's a double.

Is there a reason for this being a int32 instead of a int8 that I've totally overlooked? or is there some hidden feature in the struct that I've missed?

Comment: Probably because `Int32` is highly compiler optimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dealing with 32-bit integers no different to dealing with a smaller precision (such as Int16 or byte) in terms of performance.

So consistency is more important here than saving a few bytes here and there.

Another problem that can rise is when you try to run operations on smaller integers (addition, multiplication) and you risk the overflow or you have to cast to a bigger integer.

Answer (score 1):

int8 (a.k.a. [SByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.sbyte.aspx)):

> This API is not CLS-compliant. The CLS-compliant alternative is Int16.

It would be unusual if they decided to expose a non-CLS-compliant type in a core class library within the framework. So `int8` would definitely be the wrong choice. And then, as @Aliostad says, the fact is that shorter integral values tend to be treated as full 32-bit values during actual operations - so there's no performance benefit to using a smaller type.